# Como fazer um <div> ocupar toda a largura da página mas deixar uma lacuna de alguns pixels de cada lado em CSS?

Tags: css, html, css3

Estou tentando fazer um cabeçalho que deveria preencher toda a largura da página, mas deixando uma lacuna de 5px em cada lado. Por exemplo:

```
| ::::::::::::::: |
| ::::::::::::::: |
```

Nesse caso os pipes são a largura máxima da página e os dois pontos são um `<div>` que deveria ocupar esse espaço, de modo que quando a janela do navegador é redimensionada ele ainda ocupe toda aquela faixa, deixando lacunas de 5px dos dois lados.

Tentei fazer o seguinte:

```css
#header {
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    background-color: gray;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Mas o resultado foi esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como você pode ver ele ignorou as lacunas da direita e da esquerda, pois quando removo as linhas abaixo ele fica do mesmo jeito.

```css
padding-right: 5px;
padding-left: 5px;
```

**O que eu faço?**

---

Código HTML da página:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

O código CSS:

```css
#header {
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    background-color: gray;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
}

.left {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 700px;
    width: 10%;
    margin-top: 65px;
    background-color: gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
}

.right {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 700px;
    width: 89%;
    margin-top: 65px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: right;
}

#footer {
    height: 70px;
    background-color: gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: O `position:fixed` é mesmo uma exigência? Ou seja, você mesmo quer que o cabeçalho não role com o resto da página? Caso positivo, voc6e já tem duas respostas corretas. Se der para abrir mão do `position:fixed`, existem soluções mais simples.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[image]

A imagem mostra quatro regiões distintas, o conteúdo, o espaçamento, a borda e as margens. O que é importante notar aqui é que o espaçamento está **dentro** do elemento e vai apenas reduzir a área usada pelo conteúdo. O que acredito que você esteja tentando fazer é referente às margens, que estão por fora do elemento.

Experimente usar isso:

```css
margin-left: 5px;
margin-right: 5px;
```

O padding só é visível na renderização quando existe algum conteúdo. Experimente por um texto dentro da `div` para ver melhor o efeito.

Outro problema está no uso de `position: fixed;` (o mesmo se aplica para `position: absolute;`). Eles fazem com que o elemento fique desconectado de toda a estruturação de layout da página e não afete nenhum outro elemento, mas também não seja afetado por ele. Nessa situação o elemento não leva em consideração sua margem e leva o `width: 100%;` literalmente. Ou seja, se sua tela tem 1000px, o div terá esse tamanho, fazendo com que a margem na esquerda apenas o mova um pouco para a direita, fazendo com que saia da tela e ocultando a margem direita. O ideal é que você reestruture sua página de forma que `position: fixed;` não seja necessário. Tenho duas soluções:

1. Levar em consideração a margem manualmente:

   ```css
   width: calc(100% - 100px);
   ```

   **Nota: `calc()` faz parte do CSS3 e [não é suportado por alguns browsers mais antigos e celulares.](http://caniuse.com/calc)**
2. Remover o `position: fixed;` e o `width: 100%;` e aplicar seu efeito usando um truque com a margem inferior:

   ```css
   /*width: 100%;*/
   /*position: fixed;*/
   margin-bottom: -60px;
   ```

Exemplo: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tWkF5/2/).

Comment: Lembrando que `calc()` é do CSS3, talvez não funcione em browsers mais antigos

Comment: NÃO use calc seu layout vai ficar horrível em celulares.

Comment: realmente não é a melhor opção utilizar calc() nesse caso, mesmo excluindo da questão os Browsers antigos, em mobiles o resultado não será agradável.

Answer (score 9):

Utilize o seu primeiro código, apenas acrescente a propriedade `border-box`.
Esta propriedade vai fazer com que seu `padding` não aumente o tamanho determinado para o elemento.
E funciona a partir do IE8.

```css
#header {
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    background-color: gray;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Levando em consideração todos os tipos de dispositivos que podem acessar essa resposta realmente é melhor

Answer (score 6):

O problema aqui é que você quer ter o menu de topo (`#header`) com `position: fixed` e isso faz com que o CSS considere 100% da largura maxima do ecrã.

Assim a solução que eu vejo é usar percentagem em todo o lado, e fazer um reset ao padding e margin para jogar seguro.

O que eu usei foi:

```css
margin-left: 2%;
margin-right: 2%;
```

e fiz o width do #header a `96%`.

Assim a parte de CSS completa:

```css
* {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

#header {
    height: 70px;
    width: 96%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.left {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 700px;
    width: 10%;
    margin-top: 65px;
    background-color: gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;

}
.right {

    margin-right: 2%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 700px;
    width: 85%;
    margin-top: 65px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: right;
}
#footer {
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    clear: both;
}
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/ees9m/show/)

Answer (score 6):

Quando lidados com elementos que estão posicionados de forma fixa (`position:fixed`), podemos fazer uso das propriedades `left` e `right` para ajustar o espaçamento dos mesmos em relação à página sem necessidade de manipular o *box-model* e garantindo os 5 pixeis em qualquer dispositivo.

#### Para o teu caso em particular:

[Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/dRrCt/)

```
#header {
    height: 70px;
    margin: -10px 0 5px;
    background-color: gray;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

<sup>Retiradas as propriedades `margin-right`, `margin-left` e `width`.

Adicionadas as propriedades `left:5px` e `right:5px`.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Em elementos posicionados com Fixed ou absolute você pode utilizar as propriedades *left right top bottom* para ajustar as dimensões.
No seu caso, não seria necessário adicionar o width:100%; na div, basta setar

```
left:5px;
right:5px;
```

Para informar que o elemento deve ser posicionado a *5px* de distancia das laterais e ele automaticamente terá o width necessário para isso.

Não use **calc** se precisa de suporte IE<9

Exemplo:
[Utilizando elementos posicionados](http://jsfiddle.net/felipemorais/2Wa5P/)

Comment: Por favor, explique melhor a sua resposta. Dê um exemplo mais completo.

Answer (score 3):

Existe uma forma tranquila de fazer isso, usando apenas CSS com a propriedade box-sizing.

Veja o exemplo:

```
#header {
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 5px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Uma coisa que precisa **tomar cuidado**, é que desta forma se você for adicionar um background, o mesmo irá mostrar na **área do padding**.

Answer (score 0):

A propriedade `left` pode ser usada também.

Se usar `left: 0;` o footer/div, vai ocupar toda a margem esquerda, sem deixar espaços.

Answer (score -2):

```css
.teste{
background:red;
width:100%;
margin: auto 5px auto 0px;
padding: 8px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='teste'>Teste</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Estou agora mesmo apanhando para o CSS ('outra vez'), justamente para posicionar elementos na largura total da screen, em layouts mobile. A solução que deu certo pra mim até o momento, foi aplicar a propriedade `width` para `100%`. Contudo, o primordial para qua não houvesse aquela barra de overflow automática e assim os elementos estivessem realmente posicionados com a largura total fixa, tive que declarar as propriedades em `flex-box` logo na tag `body` do CSS.

```
@media(min-width: 160px) and (max-width: 480px){

    body{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-shrink: 1;
    }
```

Answer (score -5):

```js
var largura = $(window).width();

$('.div').css({width: largura - 10});
```

```js
css {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Por favor explique melhor a solução.