# Minha página não fica responsiva em grandes resoluções

Tags: css3, layout-responsivo

Em grandes resoluções de tela aparece a barra de rolagem horizontal na página. Estou usando toda a largura da minha tela conforme código abaixo:

```
.slides {
    width: 100vw;
}
```

Segue o exemplo:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwK2Z.jpg]

Obrigado

Comment: Por favor, reduza seu problema a um [mcve]. Postar apenas o link da sua página aqui poderá ser interpretado como spam.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como fazer um <div> ocupar toda a largura da página mas deixar uma lacuna de alguns pixels de cada lado em CSS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/360/como-fazer-um-div-ocupar-toda-a-largura-da-p%c3%a1gina-mas-deixar-uma-lacuna-de-alg)

Answer (score 1):

Removi toda sua section que contêm a classe container deixando somente a #carouselExampleIndicators

no css fiz assim:

```
#carouselExampleIndicators {
    max-width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```